# Prevent cleardoublepage in scrbook between chapters

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, scrbook

For a new term paper i want to try out a template of our university which is based on scrbook. However, my first chapter is to short (1/2 page) that the second chapter follows after a `\cleardoublepage` (it looks like this) but that is not what i want it to do. I would appreciate if is just puts the second chapter right after the first one. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a `\cleardoublepage` or is it a result of using the university template? In the second case it would seem this is desired behaviour, so you would have to stick with it?

Comment: It comes from the template, however this is a template for a Bachelor Thesis which i want to use for a longer term paper of mine. Therefore i am not bound to the "rules" in the template.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

make `\cleardoublepage` temporarely to `\relax`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\def\SpecialChap#1{{\let\cleardoublepage\relax\chapter{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\SpecialChap{bar}% no \cleardoublepage
\chapter{baz}

\end{document}
```

If you want it also for starred chapters, then use:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\def\SpecialChap{\@ifnextchar*\SpecialChap@i\SpecialChap@ii}
\def\SpecialChap@i*#1{{\let\cleardoublepage\relax\chapter*{#1}}}
\def\SpecialChap@ii{\@ifnextchar[\SpecialChap@iii\SpecialChap@iv}
\def\SpecialChap@iii[#1]#2{{\let\cleardoublepage\relax\chapter[#1]{#2}}}
\def\SpecialChap@iv#1{{\let\cleardoublepage\relax\chapter{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{foo}
    \SpecialChap{bar}% no \cleardoublepage
    \chapter{baz}
    \SpecialChap*{foobar}% no \cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

It now also allows `\SpecialChap[foo]{bar}`

Comment: It works! However i've read that i might get problems with headers which might disappear? Any idea whether this can happen?

Comment: why should they disappear?

Comment: I don't know but people complained about such a behaviour, but i will ask how to fix the problem if it really happens. For now i am satisfied :D Thanks!

Comment: Would be interesting to know how this could be change to support the starred version as well `\chapter*{Title}`. Cheers.

Comment: see edited answer